# How can I test my new app on my real iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have jailbroken iPhone. I want to test my applications on my real iPhone whithout paying $90 . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile.

Comment: Thank you! But I did it little different. Im use only steps from 1 to 9. Then I have some error and Im put my app to cracked .ipa file. Add them to iTunes and its work. But after that I can compile any app and add to iPhone from Xcode :)

Comment: There Im wrote about all my steps. Its my blog in russia language http://homeless-developer.blogspot.com/2010/03/iphone.html